# need be made vs need to be made

Tags: phrase-usage, semi-modals

"*It needs **to be** made*" is familiar, but "*it needs **be** made*" never heard of until a moment ago, and that's when @j-r wrote it in a comment. Is it standard or dialect, and if it's standard, is it informal?

J.R.'s snippet

- " The overall thrust of this answer might have a little bit of merit, but it **needs be made** much less dogmatic to be accurate and helpful."

quotes from COCA

- 2004-ACAD-TheologStud "...of the first spouse from the pagan
  marriage? The pope ruled that no inquiry **need be made** into the
  willingness of the pagan spouse to stay in the marriage,..."
- 1999-FIC-ChicagoRev "...aren't too exuberant, but rather show
  moderation in your conduct, no objections **need be made** to your
  wishes, " was the reply, and so the Robber..."
- 1993-SPOK-NPR_ATC "...tattoos on their skin or otherwise. It's not
  something that one would think **need be made** public to everyone around
  them. But what if he, for example..."

**Update:** ***need*** as a modal verb

*Needn't* = A short form of ***need not***

*-You needn't do the washing up.

-We needn't take coats with us.

-Tom needn't come if he doesn't want to.

-Diabetes needn't mean you can't enjoy your food.

-We needn't tidy up until tomorrow.*

From Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary 3rd ed.

Comment: Grammar Girl talked about *Needs washed* once. You might be intereste: http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/needs-washed

Comment: When 'need' is used as an axillary verb or modal, it does not require 's' at the end of it. So, when someone adds 's' to need, it has to be informal or dialect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Needs be made", in the context of your first quote, is just wrong, and most likely a typo in the comment. You're right, it should be "needs to be made".

However, "need be made" in the other three quotes is correct, albeit more formal and fairly rarely heard. Depending on the context, it can be equivalent to "needs to be made", "needed to be made" or "need to be made". In fact, it can probably cover any tense of "to need", and is something that the vast majority of people will be fine with just understanding it when it's used and not using it themselves.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I remember that need could be a modal verb, but that comment confused me. I'll put up some examples of using needn't from Cambridge's

Comment: For the purposes of learning english, your first paragraph can be forgiven, but it must needs be said that it is more properly called "archaic" than wrong. ( http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34788/explanation-of-must-needs http://www.thefreedictionary.com/must+needs+do etc. )

Comment: @horatio in your example, "needs" is an adverb, whereas here it is a verb. There are no cases (correct me if I'm wrong) where "needs be made" is correct where needs is a verb. I wrote that first paragraph assuming that "to need" was always assumed to be a verb, as English is such a diverse language that there are nearly always ways to make something sound right if you change it round enough!

Comment: _Need_, like _dare_, has some peculiarities in English, as explained [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/103662/15299) and [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/103303/15299) and [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/69847/15299).